# How to distribute value between fixed amount of notes

Tags: python, list, algorithm, combinations, distribution

I have 512 notes between the values ​​of 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 and 2. The sum of these notes ​​is exactly 1397. How much of each note do I have with none of them being 0?

Answer:

- 200: 1 note
- 100: 1 note
- 50: 1 note
- 20: 1 note
- 10: 1 note
- 5: 1 note
- 2: 506 notes

I know there are several possibilities, how I can write a algorithm who return at least one solution for any number of notes and any sum of values? I need to make an code in Python. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to Kelly Bundy in the comments, it turns out I'm trying to find an impossible solution with my bad example. So, with the comment edited, I arrived at this code:

```
def find_note_combinations():
    for x1 in range(1, 513):
        for x2 in range(1, 513):
            for x3 in range(1, 513):
                for x4 in range(1, 513):
                    for x5 in range(1, 513):
                        for x6 in range(1, 513):
                            for x7 in range(1, 513):
                                if x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 == 512 and 200 * x1 + 100 * x2 + 50 * x3 + 20 * x4 + 10 * x5 + 5 * x6 + 2 * x7 == 1397:
                                    return x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7

x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 = find_note_combinations()
print("Number of 200 notes:", x1)
print("Number of 100 notes:", x2)
print("Number of 50 notes:", x3)
print("Number of 20 notes:", x4)
print("Number of 10 notes:", x5)
print("Number of 5 notes:", x6)
print("Number of 2 notes:", x7)
```

But it's ugly and inefficient, help?

Comment: We need to see the code you have so far, with some information about the problems you're having.

Comment: In pseudocode or you want us to to finish what appears to be a homework problem? Pseudo would be something like: `write a dictionary that holds keys of the note values with a inital defined integer of 0`. After that, define `total=0` then `loop over created dict and while total is not 1400, add the current key to the defined "total" variable and increment the dictionary integer value for the appropriate note by 1, then  continue the loop`...there are naturally logic issues if keys are changed, and this would stop at the "200" key being added over and over if looped first, but just an example

Comment: *"how I can write a algorithm who return at least one solution for any number of notes and any sum of values?"* - You can't. For sum=3, there is no solution.

Comment: In reality, this is a coworker's problem, not mine. I work in a bank and this person has to manually count the composition of money like this. He has $12,345 in 87 bills (the counting machine reports this entry), but how much of each bill of money? There is no need for actual values, so a valid solution found by code is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursion for the task (I recommend to sort the `notes` array from lower bill to bigger one):

```py
# notes dict (we must have 1 of each at minimum)
notes = [
    [2, 1],
    [5, 1],
    [10, 1],
    [20, 1],
    [50, 1],
    [100, 1],
    [200, 1],
]

def find_solution(target, amount, notes):
    s = sum(n * a for n, a in notes)

    if amount == 0 and s == target:
        return True

    if s > target or amount < 0:
        return False

    for i in range(len(notes)):
        notes[i][1] += 1
        if find_solution(target, amount - 1, notes):
            return True
        notes[i][1] -= 1

    return False

if find_solution(1397, 512 - len(notes), notes):
    print(notes)
```

Prints:

```
[[2, 506], [5, 1], [10, 1], [20, 1], [50, 1], [100, 1], [200, 1]]
```

---

EDIT: Adding some heurestics:

```py
from itertools import product

notes = [
    [2, 1],
    [5, 1],
    [10, 1],
    [20, 1],
    [50, 1],
    [100, 1],
    [200, 1],
]

def find_solution(target, amount, notes):
    global steps
    steps += 1
    if steps > 1_000_000:
        return False

    s = sum(n * a for n, a in notes)

    if amount == len(notes):
        if target - s not in amount_shorcut:
            return False
        else:
            for val in amount_shorcut[target - s]:
                for i in range(len(notes)):
                    if notes[i][0] == val:
                        notes[i][1] += 1
                        break
            return True

    if amount == 0 and s == target:
        return True

    if s >= target or amount <= 0:
        return False

    for i in range(len(notes)):
        notes[i][1] += 1
        if find_solution(target, amount - 1, notes):
            return True
        notes[i][1] -= 1

    return False

amount_shorcut = {}
for t in product([n for n, _ in notes], repeat=len(notes)):
    amount_shorcut[sum(t)] = t

AMOUNT = 12345
N = 87
notes = sorted(notes, key=lambda l: abs(l[0] - (AMOUNT / N)))

# step 1:
steps = 0
if find_solution(AMOUNT, N - len(notes), notes):
    print(notes)
else:
    # step 2 (swap first two bills):
    steps = 0
    notes[0], notes[1] = notes[1], notes[0]
    if find_solution(AMOUNT, N - len(notes), notes):
        print(notes)

print('Total amount of steps:', steps)
```

This prints:

```
[[200, 60], [100, 2], [50, 1], [20, 2], [10, 1], [5, 1], [2, 20]]
Total amount of steps: 60434
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help, but I have a fixed amount of notes, this is the real problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, much better than mine.

Comment: can you help with a more efficient way to other combinations? Like 72 notes and 1758 sum?

Comment: @ÍtaloMachado I'm not sure if it's possible in every case. But you can try the heurestics to sort the `notes` list before calling `find_solution` (`notes = sorted(notes, key=lambda l: abs(l[0] - (AMOUNT / NUM_BILLS)))`). This will find a solution `[[20, 59], [10, 1], [5, 2], [2, 4], [50, 3], [100, 2], [200, 1]]` in short amount of time

Comment: @ÍtaloMachado `1758 / 72` is `~24,4`. So every bill in ideal case should have value `24,4`. So the heurestics by sorting is trying to first distribute bills which are close to this amount (in this case `20`, then `10` etc.)

Comment: @ÍtaloMachado I've updated my answer with some heurestics.

Comment: Amazing work, man! Thank you. Worked really great!